# Are `import package.module as module` and `from package import module` completely equivalent?

Tags: python, python-import

In normal use, they appear equivalent, but are there any subtle differences?

For example:

```bash
❯ tree package --gitignore
package
├── alias_module.py
├── from_package.py
└── module.py

1 directory, 3 files
❯ bat package/*.py
───────┬─────────────────────────────────
       │ File: package/alias_module.py
───────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1   │ import package.module as module
   2   │
   3   │ print(module.my_attr)
───────┴─────────────────────────────────
───────┬─────────────────────────────────
       │ File: package/from_package.py
───────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1   │ from package import module
   2   │
   3   │ print(module.my_attr)
───────┴─────────────────────────────────
───────┬─────────────────────────────────
       │ File: package/module.py
───────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1   │ my_attr = 10
───────┴─────────────────────────────────
❯ python -m package.alias_module
10
❯ python -m package.from_package
10
```